# How to reference ancestor container object from an ExtJS control?

Tags: javascript, parent, extjs

I am using ExtJS to build a window containing several panels as items. One of these panels contains a button.

I want to attach a handler to my button such that when I click the button, I can hide the window containing the above-mentioned panels and this button.

My question is: how can i get a reference to the parent window of my button WITHOUT referencing the window by id? I literally want a reference to the Ext.Window instance and not the Ext.Panel instance that contains my button.

Note: I do not want to reference the window by id because I am subclassing the Ext.Window class, and therefore the window's id will not always be the same. In short, I am creating a Wizard class, and when I click the wizard's Cancel button, I want to hide the wizard window containing the button.

Here is my code:

```
var newWizardWindow = new WizardWindow({
  id: 'newWizardWindow',
  title: 'New',
  items: [
    ...
  ],   
  buttons: [{
    text: 'Cancel',
    handler: function() {
      // REFERENCE WizardWindow instance here.
    }
  },{
    id: 'newWizardPreviousButton',
    text: '&laquo; Previous',
    disabled: true,
    handler: newWizardNavigator.createDelegate(this, [-1])
  },{
    id: 'newWizardNextButton',
    text: 'Next &raquo;',
    handler: newWizardNavigator.createDelegate(this, [1])
  }],
  listeners: {
    …
  }
});
```

Here are some ideas I have come up with as far as how to hide the window:

1. this.ownerCt.ownerCt (this being the button). Not favorable as with a future update to ExtJS, the number of parents between the window and the button might change.
2. Somehow store a reference to the WizardWindow instance in the WizardWindow class.
3. Find the closest WizardWindow [CSS] class in jQuery fashion: $(this).closest('.wizardWindow'). Maybe this.findByParentType('WizardWindow')?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about trying the `findParentByType(...)` method? I remember using it a few times.

> **findParentByType**(
>   String/Ext.Component/Class xtype,
>   [Boolean shallow] ) : Ext.Container
>
> *Find a container above this component
>   at any level by xtype or class.*

Here you can use the *xtype* instead of the *id* as reference and the *xtype* is the same no matter what instance you have of that type.

```
buttons: [{
    text: 'Cancel',
    handler: function() {
        // REFERENCE WizardWindow instance here.
        var parentWindow = this.findParentByType('xtypelizardwindow');
    }
}]
```

Comment: I wish I could give this answer a +10 :)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the ref as scope.

```
buttons: [{
    text: 'Cancel',
    scope:this,
    handler: function() {
    }
}]
```

Comment: Here, wouldn't "this" be the button? Is that your intention?

Comment: Hmm, if you use 'this' inline, I do not think it will work. I asked a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588968/extjs-button-scope

Comment: this does work, and fyi is the proper way to do this! `this` inside the handler will become the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

In your configuration for your button, as a sibling to your handler property, can you add a scope: newWizardWindow property? I'm not 100% sure if that will work, but I think it will. This will set the scope of your button handler to be the window, and inside the handler function you can just do this.hide();

Comment: have u tried this? I've used this method in a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588968/extjs-button-scope and Chau above answered it....

Answer (score 0):

this.ownerCt will also gives reference to parent object, which is container.
as it is using the this.findParentByType(parent xtype)