# extjs button scope

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I am trying to understand scope in the below scenario. When calling `searchTerms`, `this` under the `scope:this` refers to the `searchTerms` function rather than the panel itself. It seems to be different from what I observe from other examples. May I know what mistakes did i make?

```
function searchTerms(){
       var searchGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({

        });

        var searchPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
            region: 'south',
            height:150,
            items:[
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Keywords',
            },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Label',
            },{
                xtype: 'datefield',
                fieldLabel: 'Valid till'
            },new Ext.Button({
                text: 'crawl',
                scope: this,
                handler: function(b,e){
                    Ext.Ajax.request({^M
                        url: '/discovery/tsearch',^M
                        params: {^M
                            keywords: this.items[0].getValue(),
                            label: this.items[1].getValue(),
                            valid: this.items[2].getValue(),
                        },
                    });
                }
            }),],
        });

        var regionPanel = new Ext.Panel({
            title: 'search',
            layout: 'border',
            items: [searchPanel, searchGrid]
        });

    return regionPanel;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you meant to do this:

```
function searchTerms(){
   var searchGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({

    });

    var searchPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        region: 'south',
        height:150,
        items:[
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Keywords',
        },{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Label',
        },{
            xtype: 'datefield',
            fieldLabel: 'Valid till'
        }],
    });
    searchPanel.add(new Ext.Button({
            text: 'crawl',
            scope: searchPanel,
            handler: function(b,e){
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: '/discovery/tsearch',
                    params: {
                        keywords: this.items[0].getValue(),
                        label: this.items[1].getValue(),
                        valid: this.items[2].getValue(),
                    },
                });
            }
        })
    );
    var regionPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        title: 'search',
        layout: 'border',
        items: [searchPanel, searchGrid]
    });

return regionPanel;
}
```

Comment: This is a scoping problem, 'this' would be the searchTerm object when you create the button and not the searchPanel, you have to think about the score when the code would be first executed not when the event comes

Comment: The difference is that the button is *added* to the searchPanel and the scope is set to the searchPanel. To be able to set the scope to the searchPanel, the searchPanel has to be defined first - which is not possible when you create the button *inline* inside the searchPanel. Does that make sence?

Comment: @Chau: yes, make perfect sense, that's why I had to use `add`, if you want to do it inline, I think you should get the reference of the searchPanel by using the parentContainer or using some id and getCmp

Comment: @RageZ: The comment wasn't meant for you :) I have never thought of using a reference function like `getCmp` but it might actually work.

Comment: hmm @RageZ I'm a little confused partially due to this article. http://www.sencha.com/learn/legacy/Tutorial:What_is_that_Scope_all_about2#Specifying_the_Scope_in_Ext So let me clarify, the 'this' for the link example is determined only when the object's function is called, hence the object itself. Whereas in my case, 'this' is determined during the object creation, hence it refers to the searchTerm object....

Comment: If you ever use getCmp you are organizing your ExtJS application absolutely 1000% *WRONG*